# Section Break (Odd Page) NOT creating blank page. Microsoft Word 2010, Win 7 Enterprise

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2010

So I've got the opposite problem than most people who are having trouble with section breaks. I'm working on a lengthy document with multiple sections where the page numbering restarts in the new section. If, for example, one section ends on page 13, and I insert Section Break (Odd Page) and set the next page number to "1", and continue typing, when I go to print my document, Page "1" of section 2 prints on the backside of page "13" from section 1. The blank "even" page is not inserted.

I can duplicate this functionality in a blank word document, too: I turned on page numbering, inserted some test text, inserted a section break (odd page) and set both pages to be page 1. Rather than printing on two pieces of paper, the second page "1" was printed on the backside of the first page "1" (what should have been the blank page "2").

How do I fix it so that the blank "even" pages are inserted again?